# How do I recover data from a Logical Volume on Linux after deleting it?

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm, luks

Yesterday I was trying to shrink my Gentoo Linux partition with LUKS encryption to make place for another distribution, but because it was an LVM partition I was just trying random commands from the internet not knowing what they did which was fairly stupid.
I have 3 Logical volumes, */dev/mapper/vg0-root*, */dev/mapper/vg0-var* and */dev/mapper/vg0-home*.

I ended up accidentally running *mke2fs* on my */dev/mapper/vg0-home* partition, and afterwards I found out that this formatted my partition to an ext2 partition and that I lost all my data.

*Testdisk* didn't find anything because I don't think it can recover files on logical volumes and *vgcfgrestore* didn't result in any luck either.

Comment: "just trying random commands from the internet not knowing what they did which was fairly stupid": That is correct. Occasionally you can even find articles that deliberately provide disastrous instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are largely out of luck. Photorec can help you recover some fragments of your disk (mainly images and documents in known formats), but not filenames, directory structure or files where they span fragments.

Photorec is part of the testdisk suite. Testdisk itself does not look for documents, it looks for partitions, which is why it didn't find any files.